# How to build a highly secure End to End Encryption React Native messaging app

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, diffie-hellman, end-to-end-encryption

I just posted this question on security stackexchange and they advised me to move my question to stackoverflow so here it is.

I am currently working on an instant React Native messaging app and I want to implement E2EE (End to End Encryption between the sender and the receiver) for better security. The libraries/frameworks I use are NodeJS for the backend, Socket.io for real-time communication, MongoDB for data management and obviously React Native for the frontend.

At this point, I am able to send messages back and forth from sender to the server and back to the receiver but the server can actually read the messages which is quite anoying because I want to save the messages (encrypted) in my database and retrieve them for the user to see his history.

Recently I found that the Diffie-Hellman key-exchange was a good solution to generate a shared secret key on each endpoint device but I don't know how to implement it in my app.

I also found that big messaging app (like WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, Signal,... ) uses the Signal Protocol which is based on a X3DH (Extended Triple Diffie-Hellman) and I was wondering if it is possible to implement such a good thing in my RN app. But the problem is that even after reading the Signal Protocol's documentation I could not figure out how to implement it.

In conclusion my question is how can I implement the Signal Protocol in my RN app and uses Socket.io to send and receive encrypted messages? And if for some reason this is not possible, how can I implement the Diffie-Hellman key-exchange algorithm?

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: I was also trying to implement `Diffie-Hellman key-exchange algorithm` and I found one package named `react-native-crypto` but it seems too old and too complex to use.

If you found any solution then please would you please mind to share it with me as well?

Comment: any updates on this?